# Python list: why append the same value

Tags: python

I create these for loops and at the end I append the value of a dict to a list, but every time I do append, it appends the same value in my list and  don't know why.

My code:

```
data_list = []
with open(arquivo, encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for jsonObj in f:
        data = json.loads(jsonObj)
        count = count + 1

        for item in data:
            if item in de:
                indice = de.index(item)
                data_new[para[indice]] = data[item]
            else:
                data_new[item] = data[item]

        data_list.append(data_new)

    print(data_list)
```

Expected:

```
[{"a": 1}, {"b":2}]
```

Real result:

```
[{"a": 1}, {"a":1}]
```

My file is something like that:

```
{"Line1":"value","Key1":0}
{"Line2":"value","Key2":0}
{"Line3":"value","Key3":0}
```

And one thing that I discovered: if I write a file instead `data_list.append()` it works, in the same indent. So in `data_list.append(data_new)` I changed to call `write_file(data_new)`:

```
write_file(data_new):
    with open('test.json', 'a') as f:
        json.dump(data, f)
        f.write('\n')
```

Obs.:
printing and debuging I can see the value of `data_list` (*list*) and in the first append, the value is correct:

```
{"Line1":"value","Key1":0}
```

in the second time inside the loop the value of data_new is `"Line2"` (correctly) but when I do `data_list.append(data_new)` it changes all my array to the very last readed and so on:

```
{"Line2":"value","Key2":0}
{"Line2":"value","Key2":0}
```

_

```
def write_file(data):
    with open('data-transfer-out-teste.json', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        json.dump(data, f)
        f.write('\n')


def main():
    config = ler_config()
    de = config["de"]
    para = config["para"]
    data_new = {}

    arquivo = "entrada.json"

    with open(arquivo, encoding="utf-8") as f:
        for jsonObj in f:
            data = json.loads(jsonObj)
            count = count + 1

            # item = chaves no arquivo lido
            # indice = posicao da chave no array "de"
            for item in data:
                if item in de:
                    indice = de.index(item)
                    data_new[para[indice]] = data[item]
                else:
                    data_new[item] = data[item]

            write_file(data_new)
```

Comment: Can you show the contents of arquivo? Or a sample?

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Answer (score 2):

I may be wrong, but it seems that you need to add an indentation here:

```py
data_list = []
with open(arquivo, encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for jsonObj in f:
        data = json.loads(jsonObj)
        count = count + 1

        for item in data:
            if item in de:
                indice = de.index(item)
                data_new[para[indice]] = data[item]
            else:
                data_new[item] = data[item]

            data_list.append(data_new) ### here to add

    print(data_list)
```